# Using print_r in ob_start

Tags: php

As mentioned in the manual it's not working. i tried var_dump it too suffers from the same problem.

```
ob_start()
$debugdata=print_r ($var,true)
```

This prints the result on screen than storing to a variable

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: From the PHP documentation:

When the return parameter is used, this function uses internal output buffering so it can not be used inside an ob_start() callback function."

More info here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second parameter of print_r is `$return` which allows the output to be returned as a string rather than outputting it:

```
$debugData = print_r($var, true);
```

There is no need to use output buffering for this, and in fact it cannot be used. You will need to end the output buffering before this and then restart the buffering after your print_r call:

```
ob_start();
// stuff
$output = ob_end_clean();

$debugData = print_r($var, true);

ob_start();
// more stuff
$output .= ob_end_clean();
```

**EDIT**: Another option is to nest output buffers and have an inner buffer do the print_r work:

```
ob_start(); // your original start  
// stuff

ob_start();
print_r($var);
$debugData = ob_get_clean();

// more stuff 
$output = ob_get_clean(); // your original end
```

Answer (score 3):

`ob_start()` starts outbut buffering. But you also need to end and retrieve the contents of the buffer as well.

Here are the functions you could use:

`ob_get_clean()` - puts the contents of the output buffer in a variable, ends and cleans the buffer.

```
ob_start();
print_r($foo);
$output = ob_get_clean();
```

`ob_get_contents()` - fetches the contents of the output buffer without closing or cleaning it.

`ob_end_clean()` - closes and cleans the buffer.

```
ob_start();
print_r($foo);
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

There are a few other possibilities. [Please make yourself familiar with the output buffering functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php).

Also, a remark. You don't just assign the output of `print_r` to a variable. You just print stuff as if you were printing it on the screen. With output buffering on, all output will be buffered instead of being sent to stdout immediately. So, first you `print_r`, then retrieve the contents of the buffer.

[EDIT]

In the light of the conversation going on in the comments, I recommend having a look at the notes section of the `print_r()` [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php#refsect1-function.print-r-notes). As @RomiHalasz and @cbuckley observe, due to `print_r`'s internal output buffering, it cannot be used in conjunction with `ob_start()`
while the second parametre, *return*, is used, as the two will collide.

You have to EITHER use output buffering and plain `print_r` (with only the first parametre), or end the output buffering before you use `print_r` with the second parametre.

Either this:

```
ob_start();
print_r($foo);
$output = ob_get_clean();
```

or this:

```
ob_start();
// blah
$output = ob_get_clean();

$output .= print_r($foo,true);

ob_start();
// blah
$output .= ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: See the manual for print_r. It can be assigned to a variable, but it is this that conflicts with the output buffering.

Comment: Either I'm not making things clear, or you haven't read my answer carefully. With output buffering, you DON'T NEED TO make `print_r` return a string. You can simply let it send it to stdout, like in the examples I've provided. Output buffering will collect that.

Comment: OK, I just understood your remark in the context of your answer. Indeed, you can either assign the output of `print_r` to a value using its 2nd parametre OR let it print to stdout while using output buffering. Seems both our answers are correct :D.

Comment: Assuming the OP is already in an output buffer, and wishes to have access to `$debugdata` within that buffer, I think this answer would benefit in making it clear that this solution works if it is used as a nested output buffer. In fact, IMO that's a better solution than mine :-)

Comment: I am not going to use qualitative categorising here. Both approaches work, thus both are correct. It is unclear whether the OP uses output buffering for the sole purpose of capturing the output of `print_r` or not ;). Either way, you have my upvote.